# jQuery: Get option innerHTML of first option with value set in HTML select tag

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

Suppose I have a dropdown (select tag) with 3 values.  Our first option has a value of "".  The second option has a value of "something".  And the 3rd option has a value of "something else".  How can I get the innerHTML (text) of the 2nd option?  I don't want to hard code it such that it takes the 2nd option every time though.  I want to make sure it's the first option with a value set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = $('#selectId option[value!=""]').first().html();
```

or:

```
var result = $('#selectId option[value!=""]:first').html();
```

[Attribute Not Equal selector:](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

> Description: Select elements that either don't have the specified attribute, or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.

[:first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

> Description: Selects the first matched element.
>   The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq(0). It could also be written as :lt(1)

**Note** that all of the `<option>`s **must have** the `value` attribute in order for the selector to work as expected.  If it's not guaranteed use this:

```
var result = $('#selectId option[value!=""][value]:first').html();
```

[Has Attribute Selector [name]](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.

Comment: +1 Suppose I wanted to select that rather than just getting the innerhtml.  Would I just set the attr function of "selected" to "selected"?

Comment: @MacGyver Yes: `$('#selectId option[value!=""]').first().attr('selected', 'selected')`

Comment: If you've got value setting for all options, this will always return the first option, but you can change it to say something like `$('#selectId option[selected!=""]').first().html();`

Answer (score 1):

If i am getting right you want to get 2nd elment from dropdown try

```
   $('select[name=thename] option:eq(1)').text();​
```

Comment: Where is the value not empty part? Read the question again please: _"I don't want to hard code it such that it takes the 2nd option every time though. I want to make sure it's the first option with a value set."_

Answer (score 0):

I like simple, so I'll give you two ways that I would do it depending on the structure.  I don't usually select by name, because the code is more complex and IMO unnecessary.

If the HTML only has a class without an id:

```
<select class='example'>
    <option value=''>Text 0</option>
    <option value='something'>Text 1</option>
    <option value='something else'>Text 2</option>
</select>

$('select.example option:eq(1)').text();  // Text 1
```

If the HTML has an id, this is the most efficient way to get the text:

```
<select id='example'>
    <option value=''>Text 0</option>
    <option value='something'>Text 1</option>
    <option value='something else'>Text 2</option>
</select>

$('#example option:eq(1)').text();  // Text 1
```